# Using linux wget to grab data from windows box

Tags: linux, wget

I need to get the data from Windows box and store it on my linux box using wget.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
user="vim1"
pass="pass11"
host="10.20.15.124"
#from this folder
localbase="C:/Users/i1/Desktop/datafolder"
remotebase="/home/myfolder"

wget_opts="-q"
```

When I run

```
wget  --user=vim1 --password='pass11' 10.20.15.124
```

it does nothing. Just says

```
Connecting to 10.20.15.124:80...
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You need to run an HTTP or FTP server on your Windows box. Do you? Can you connect to it with a browser? Do you see `C:/Users/i1/Desktop/datafolder` in the URL?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No I cannot connect that way. I tried. I can remote desktop into 10.20.15.124 @n.m.

Comment: Then you cannot connect with `wget` either. Back to step one. You need to run an HTTP or FTP server on your Windows box. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, if you don't have an HTTP or FTP server up and running on your Windows box you will have problems connecting to it through internet. Until you have resolved that, a relatively fast way to transfer your files would be through [sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet) if you have physical access to the Windows box.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @n.m. and @htor, you need to have an HTTP server running on your Windows machine to be able to connect this way. What you can do is use [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to mount a shared folder from your Windows box on your Linux box and copy the files to a local folder on your Linux box (google buzzword: `smbmount`).

Answer (score 1):

If by any lucky accident you have Python on your source machine, then you can use the preinstalled [SimpleHTTPServer module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) to serve your file over HTTP. Go to the folder with your file and run

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

or if you have Python 3

```
python3 -m http.server
```

And then on your Linux machine use

```
wget http://<source-machine-IP>:8000/<filename>
```

The module allows to specify an optional PORT parameter, if the default 8000 port is not suitable for you.